# Limiting result using ORM kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I have written code

```
ORM::factory('cds')->find_all(1, 2);
```

It is returning all row . But according to documentation it should return 2 row. 
what's wrong in the code ?
http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm

Comment: What kohana version do you use?

Comment: That code will return one record starting from row #2. What are you trying to get? And, as @zerkms said, it's also important which version of Kohana you are using.

Comment: @ I am using version 3.1

Comment: Please forget that link, read http://kohanaframework.org/guide/3.1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Kohana v3 the valid way to perform limit is:

```
ORM::factory('cds')->limit(2)->find_all();
```

Comment: how to give starting index (offset )?

Comment: got limit(5)->offset($start)->find_all();

Comment: @Vivek Goel: by default offset is `0`, you can change it to any `N` with `->offset(N)`